# Get slidingMenu drawer state

Tags: java, android

I am using [this library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) to implement slidingmenu in my application
but in one of my tasks I want to get the state of the drawer i.e whether it is open or closed I couldn't find relevant classes in the library or did I miss something?
how do I accomplish this?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using a `SlidingActivity`. From inside that activity
just call `getSlidingMenu().isMenuShowing()` to get the state of the menu.